# What codes are invovled in running an overhead subpanel feeder to a detached garage?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

This subfeeder will be going to a detached garage about 30ft away, and powering a 100amp subpanel. I'm not sure what codes are involved in this feat. I'd like to know the codes involved for compliance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to write something up for you. If nobody else answers, and I get a chance I'll try to write something up tomorrow.

Comment: Many, many codes are involved. Did you have a specific question? Or are you asking how to do every aspect of this job??

Comment: @SpeedyPetey what codes or where they're located is my specific question, actually running the wire seems pretty intuitive, but if you have some advice, I'm all ears.

Comment: Start with article 225 of the NEC.  You'll need to be concerned with the point of attachment to each building, the point of entrance to each building, and clearances under the feeder.  Easy answer is: Install a mast with weather head atop each building, and run a messenger wire between them. Then run the conductors along the messenger wire, and into the weather heads. There's a ton of code sections involved, so providing a compete step by step here would be difficult, especially without being able to see the site.

Comment: Actually, it's not as intuitive as you think. The codes involved are Chapters 2 and 3 of the NEC. It's not like there is a list of codes involved in a certain job. Electrical codes are convoluted and can be very non-specific as to the job being done, meaning something in the code might very well apply and be in a section a lay person might not ever think to look.

Comment: Bottom line is, it is much more difficult, and code intensive to run overhead as opposed to underground.

Comment: Thnx @SpeedyPetey, but if you check my questions,  in this situation it might be *easier* to just run overhead following codes than underground :-(

Comment: @BigHomie Check with the local building department, they should be able to tell you what they expect to see when they do the inspection. I've found that my local building department is very helpful, and seems to enjoy helping DIYers. Speedy Petey is right when he says that the codes involved are numerous. I started to go through and highlight all the articles you might need, and lets just say that if I was using an actual highlighter, it would have been out of ink.

Comment: I found [this document (PDF)](http://bloomingtonmn.gov/handouts/53/53fffdetach.pdf) from the Bloomington, Minnesota building department, just as an example of the types of documents they have. Your local building department might have something similar.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it if you want. But make sure the wires are wet rated and they are at least 12 feet above the ground according to the NEC Good Luck with your project.

Comment: That's...not sufficient.  UF by itself is wet rated, but you can't run UF by itself in an overhead app, due to it not having enough structural strength for the job!